# Is there a way to upgrade laptop's USB2.0 to USB 3.0?

Tags: usb, usb-3

Is there a way to upgrade laptop's USB 2.0 ports to USB 3.0? If so, will the changes be a driver update alone or will it require changes in the internal hardware?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[USB 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usb_3) is a different technology that uses slightly different connectors and – most importantly – is not upwards compatible in the sense of "just install a new driver and it works".

> To accommodate the additional pins for SuperSpeed mode, the physical form factors for USB 3.0 plugs and receptacles have been modified.

That means you can run USB 3 devices on a USB 2 port, but they will only work in a legacy mode that does not support the USB 3 transfer rates.

Your options are:

- Buy an expansion card that offers USB 3.0 ports, for example if your laptop has a [ExpressCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresscard) slot
- Get a new motherboard, which of course is not a straightforward procedure for a laptop

Answer (score 4):

No.  This requires a hardware upgrade.  You will need and Expresscard adapter.[Startech](http://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/USB-3.0/Cards?fam_filter=ExpressCard)   has several and there are a number of other vendors as well.